# Java showInputDialog select custom text

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have rename dialog for rename file

```
String renameTo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(gui, "New Name", currentFile.getName());
```

it works this way, but I have a problem.
the problem is that I set the default value with the extension of the file
but I just want the file name to be selected.

```
sample : my file name = yusuf.png
```

I want select only yusuf like;

[image: like this]

Comment: You can't control the `JTextField` used by `JOptionPane`, you'll need to role your own implementation. You could get started by having a look at [`JTextComponent#setSelectionStart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setSelectionStart-int-) and [`JTextComponent#setSelectionEnd`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setSelectionEnd-int-)

Comment: "Easiest" is subjective - besides, why would we show you the hardest way to do something ... we're lazy after all ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot going on inside `JOptionPane`, it's one of the things that makes it so powerful, it also makes it a little inflexible to.

Two immediate problems are apparent...

1. You can't gain direct access to the `JTextField` been used to get input from the user
2. The `JOptionPane` wants to control which components have focus when the dialog is first shown.

Setting up the `JTextField` is actually straight forward...

```
String text = "yusuf.png";
int endIndex = text.lastIndexOf(".");

JTextField field = new JTextField(text, 20);
if (endIndex > 0) {
    field.setSelectionStart(0);
    field.setSelectionEnd(endIndex);
} else {
    field.selectAll();
}
```

This will basically select all the text from the start of the `String` up to the last `.` or all the text if no `.` can be found.

The difficult part now is taking back focus control from the `JOptionPane`

```
// Make a basic JOptionPane instance
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(field, 
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
        null);
// Use it's own dialog creation process, it's simpler this way
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("Rename");
// When the window is displayed, we want to "steal"
// focus from what the `JOptionPane` has set
// and apply it to our text field
dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        // Set a small "delayed" action
        // to occur at some point in the future...
        // This way we can circumvent the JOptionPane's
        // focus control
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                field.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
    }
});
// Put it on the screen...
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.dispose();
// Get the resulting action (what button was activated)
Object value = pane.getValue();
if (value instanceof Integer) {
    int result = (int)value;
    // OK was actioned, get the new name
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        String newName = field.getText();
        System.out.println("newName = " + newName);
    }
}
```

And, crossing our fingers, we end up with something looking like...

[image: Example]

Personally, I'd wrap this up in a nice reusable class/method call which returned the new text or `null` based on the action of the user, but that's me

> Isn't there an easier way?

Of course, I just like showing you the most difficult solution possible ...  (sarcasm) ... it's kind of why I suggested wrapping it up in it's own utility class, so you can re-use it later